# Strip the First Four Rows of a CSV in Python?

Tags: python, csv, delete-row

I have a batch of 50-60 csv files which, for whatever reason, have total junk data for the first four rows of each file. After the junk data, however, the column headers are properly listed, and the rest of the file is fine. How could I go about stripping each file of these first four files in python? Here is my code thus far:

```
import csv
total = open('C:\\Csv\\201.csv', 'rb')
for row in csv.reader(total):
    print row
```

As you can see, all I have done is opened the file and printed its contents. I have searched around for solutions of deleting certain aspects of csv files, but most either delete entire columns, or hinge on a particular condition for the row to be deleted. In my case, it is simply a matter of order, and every file needs to be stripped of its first four rows. Any and all  help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i, line in enumerate(sys.stdin, -4):
    if i>=0: print line,
```

Answer (score 8):

You could do:

```
reader = csv.reader(total)
all(next(reader) for i in range(4))
```

or

```
for i in range(4): next(reader)
```

Comment: That's creative. I never would have thought to use "any".

Comment: `any` only skip the first line, `all` skips all four lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a generic function to skip the first n items of any sequence:

```
def skip_first(seq, n):
    for i,item in enumerate(seq):
        if i >= n:
            yield item
```

To use it:

```
import csv
with open('C:\\Csv\\201.csv', 'rb') as total:
    csvreader = csv.reader(total)
    for row in skip_first(csvreader, 4):
        print row
```

This function is generic because it can skip over any sequence, not just file:

```
# Skip the first three
list = ['happy', 'grumpy', 'doc', 'sleepy', 'bashful', 'sneezy', 'dopey']
for item in skip_first(list, 3):
    print item
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no one has suggested the Pythonic way of using `islice` here...

```
from itertools import islice
with open('somefile') as fin:
    csvin = islice(csv.reader(fin), 4, None, None)
    for row in csvin:
        pass
```

example:

```
>>> r = range(10); list(islice(r, 4, None, None))
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers seem to be taking the header line required for `DictReader` into account: unless the first line contains anything else than the list of fields, `DictReader` won't recognize them and parse properly.

And because `csv.reader` expects file-like object, I had to use `StringIO` as a temporary buffer (not a serious issue, I have about 20 rows there usually).

```
with StringIO() as csvio:
    for i, line in enumerate(myfile.iter_lines()):
        if i < 5:
            continue
        else:
            csvio.write(line)

    reader = csv.DictReader(csvio)
```

Would appreciate better suggestions how to create file-like objects for all the lines except first N without buffering if all in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I surprised no one mentioned the parameter available to `skiprows` while calling the read function.

```
df = pd.read_csv('somefile.csv',skiprows=4)
```

You can check the file for rows containing the header and give value to `**skiprows**` as per it removes the first k rows if the value is k.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do to skip the first four rows in the file

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users//...",skiprows=4)
```